# How to make Label's text centered vertically?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I tried one by one each of these methods : setting the BgAlign property to CENTER in the Resource Editor , `myLabel.getStyle().setBackgroundAlignment(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGN_CENTER);` but the text of the Label is not centered vertically.

So how to make Label's text centered vertically ?

The following image shows the actual alignement of the Label's text :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label vertical alignment is unsupported only its positioning in relation to an icon.

As far as I recall you are using `FlowLayout` for every entry which does support vertical alignment see `FlowLayout.setValign(Component.CENTER)`.